# how to add div content to mysql without using form element

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to save div content into mysql without using form and button means page should be opened in browser and it should send it's all div content to mysql table automatically.

here it is what i tried

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){getElement()},5000);
function getElement()
{
  var iBody = $("#frametest").contents().find(".bx-viewport").html();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml=iBody;
  alert(iBody);
}
```

i want this demo div to be saved in mysql

Comment: post some code you have tried so far.

Comment: ajax call using jquery? it all depends on how you decide to structure your data

Comment: please give any reference site name if you know any

Comment: If you you want it to be save on loading, use: onload in the body tag

Comment: I have to save it after some interval So i am already using setInterval please give any detail about how i can save div content to mysql

Comment: if anybody have some useful information please share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use forms, I think AJAX is a great option.

```
var contents = $('#frametest').contents().find('.bx-viewport').html();
$.ajax({
  url: 'path/to/php/script',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {content: contents},
  success: function() {
    // do something after sending data
  }
});
```

This will send `contents` to the php script defined in the `url` property of the AJAX call as a POST request, and in the php script you can use the normal thing you'd do for saving it in MySQL.